# How do I recurse in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Here's my code

```
import scrapy
class PvSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'pv'
   allowed_domains = ['www.piaov.com']
   start_urls = ['http://www.piaov.com/']

   def start_requests(self):
       yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.piaov.com/list/7.html')

   def parse(self, response):
       names = response.xpath("//ul[@class='mlist']//li/a/@title").extract()
       on = response.meta.get("names", [])
       cmp_names = on + names
       for p in range(2, 7):
           yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.piaov.com/list/7_{}.html'.format(p),
                                meta={"names": cmp_names},
                                callback=self.parse)

       yield scrapy.Request("http://www.piaov.com", meta={"names": cmp_names}, callback=self.parse_item)

   def parse_item(self, response):
       pass
```

When i debug my code in 'parse_item' function,the 'response.meta["names"]' only include the first page datas(12 titles in this case), how could i get the 6 pages datas list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have URL http://www.piaov.com and scrapy ignores the duplicate URLs unless `dont_filter=True` is specified in `Request` like `Request(url_here, dont_filter=True)`

Also I don't like your logic of scraper, why are you calling `parse_item` at all? it is not necessary. Please see the code below and do it like that.

```
import scrapy
class PvSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'pv'
   allowed_domains = ['www.piaov.com']
   start_urls = ['http://www.piaov.com/']

   def start_requests(self):
       yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.piaov.com/list/7.html')

   def parse(self, response):
       for name in response.xpath("//ul[@class='mlist']//li/a/@title").extract():

            yield {"name": name}

       for p in range(2, 7):
           yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.piaov.com/list/7_{}.html'.format(p),
                                callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: calling parse_item because this's a demo for my real project.In my real project, i need parse something in 'parse_item' function.I need parse content in the first of my project, then i need parse comments which actually return in JSON DATA(titles instead in this case) ,the last step is crawl client's 'like' which also return in JSON DATA, so i have the logic above.Because I'm testing the 'meta' data.

Comment: @ZeeBmChan if you really want to call `parse_item` call it like `yield self.parse_item(cmp_names)` and then process names in there. No need to yield a request to same URL `http://www.piaov.com` again and again. But still if you want to make request, specify `dont_filter=True` so scrapy will not ignore the duplicate request